# Adjusting UINavigationController height

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there a way I can make my UINavigationController height a certain size? I don't want it to take up the whole height? I would like to put a toolbar at the bottom.  Or is there a preferred way to do this?

Comment: If you want to add tootlbar than add it in ViewController why u want to resize it?

Answer (score 1):

You can add the bottom toolbar as subview of the viewcontroller.
There is no need for resizing

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't make sense. A controller doesn't have a height.
You might be talking about the `UINavigationBar` but it does not take the entire height if the screen.
And if you are using a `UINavigationController`, then you also have a toolbar as a property all set up for you.

Just set the `toolbarItems` property in your view controller.
[Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/toolbarItems)

Comment: I am using the DDMenuController component and would like to add a toolbar at the bottom. I was wondering how best to do that. I dont want to add a toolbar in every VC but just one main one and have the DDMenuController hieght 80% of the main view

Comment: I haven't used that component so I can't answer your question. But my guess is that you have to add UIToolbar as a subview and place it at the bottom